# Does "entire" mean the same thing as "antiderivative exists"?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, terminology, complex-integration, entire-functions

I often see an integral such as this:

$$\int a^z dz$$ where $a \ne 0$, for $z$ complex.

And then in the solution I see justification like the following:

Since $a^z$ "is an entire function, its primitive is given by"  $$\frac{a^{z}}{
Log (a)}$$.

This seems to imply the following:

*If a function is entire, then its antiderivative exists*.

Now, I know it is true that if a function is entire, then it is differentiable everywhere, but is it *also* true that its antiderivative exists if it is entire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In any simply-connected domain, a holomorphic function has an anti-derivative. In particular, this is true on $\mathbb C$.

$F(z)=\int_{\gamma } f(\xi)d\xi$ where $\gamma$ is the line segment from $0$ to $z$ defines the anti-derivative when the domain is $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: And is the converse also true?  I.e. does anti-derivative existing, imply the function is entire?

Comment: Yes, the derivative of an entire function is also entire so the converse is also true. @nundo